# HDFS single writer multiple reader model - read inconsistency?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

HDFS allows single writer multiple reader model. In this model - can it face a situation where data read is not consistent with what the writer is writing? HDFS doesn't guarantee visibility of data until an explicit h-flush operation is performed but what if the data read by reader is changed by writer - won't it be a data inconsistency issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario , in which the data read by the reader will be changed by the writer, will not at all happen in HDFS.

As you correctly observed, HDFS supports `write once` model, where it will not allow any modification of the written data.

So once the `FSDataOutputStream.hsync()` is called, the data will be written to the disk and the clients can read the data , writers will not have any way to modify the flushed data.

The only way to modify the contents is to duplicate the same data with required changes.

Edit:-

The design facts in HDFS that make us to read the recently written blocks of the file which is being copied ,as soon as the blocks are flushed outs, are mostly for *tracking the progress of the complete file write operation, to avoid failures on file closing and also to support `hadoop fs -tail`* command.

Please refer ,

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-89

HDFS only guarantees the `Eventual consistency` where the the blocks of the file will be consistent across the distributed system only after the client closes the file write operation.

-- courtesy @sunrise76

Comment: Make sense. One scenario: Writer is going to write 512KB but he just flushed 256KB of data that was read by the reader. Eventually writer will write 512KB but since the reader has only read 256KB of new data - won't it affect read consistency in this case? or do we follow eventual consistency model here?

Comment: it follows eventual consistency

Comment: @yguw, I have edited the answer. Kindly check if it is helpful.